# Xamarin.Forms - ControlTemplate doesn't display ContentPresenter

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use a ControlTemplate so I can have a footer on every page, but whenever I use the template, *only* the template is shown and the page content disappears. It's almost as if the `ContentPresenter` isn't rendering the page content, only the template content. I have been using [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating) to get the template working, but with no avail.

Here's my template code:

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="TestApp.App">
   <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MainFooter">
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter/>
                <Label Text="Template footer" FontSize="24"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And the page code:

```
<ContentPage Title="Test" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         x:Class="TestApp.Login">
    <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MainFooter}" Padding="0, 20, 0, 0">

        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Page content" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>


    </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

As you can see from the output of this code, only the ContentTemplate is being displayed, and not the "Page Content" label (ContentPresenter content). How can I display page content as well as template content?

[image: page output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall for a while, it seems that the page content *is* actually being rendered once I start up the app in the simulator.

**The previewer only displays the ControlTemplate, and not the page content**, once a ControlTemplate has been applied. Most likely a bug in Visual Studio, so did some digging:

[Relatively old Bugzilla, same problem](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52889)

[Someone else with the same problem](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/121286/preview-of-page-using-control-tempate-does-not-show-controls-contained-in-content-presented)

I'm using Visual Studio 7.7.4 and Xamarin 5.2.1.15. Guess I'll just have to take the ControlTemplate off whenever I want to preview my page.