# ContentPresenter not showing content inside ControlTemplate Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create a reusable template page that I want to use throughout my app.

I decided to go with a `ControlTemplate` to achieve this but I am having issues. The first issue is that the `HeaderText` does not get displayed when I bind to it. The second issue is that the Page using this ControlTemplate does not have his children visible, the ContentPresenter is empty.

ControlTemplate:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Project.MainViewTemplate">
<ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label TextColor="Black"
                   Text="{TemplateBinding HeaderText}"
                   BackgroundColor = "Green"
                   Grid.Row="0"/>

            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
```

And its code behind:

```
public partial class MainViewTemplate : ContentPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(HeaderText), typeof(string), typeof(MainViewTemplate), default(string));

    public string HeaderText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public MainViewTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Page that uses it:

```
<template:MainViewTemplate xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                       x:Class="Project.MainView"
                       xmlns:template="clr-namespace:Project"
                       HeaderText="Main view">
     <StackLayout Margin="10"
                  BackgroundColor="Green">
         <Label Text = "Test"/>
     </StackLayout>
</template:MainViewTemplate>
```

The label that binds `HeaderText` is not showing its text, if i change it to write hardcoded text it works, so something is off with the binding. Secondly, I can see the green background as well. Secondly, the contentpresenter is not showing the content inside the page that uses this ControlTemplate.

Comment: Hey, I don't see any problem with the code you posted. Are you running this on Android or iOS?

Comment: iOS, but not tested on android yet @pinedax .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you use Template in your code correctly, I do one sample that you can take a look:

ControlTemplate, there one control x:key="template1"

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="demo3.template.MainViewTemplate"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="template1">
        <Grid RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label
                Grid.Row="0"
                BackgroundColor="Green"
                Text="{TemplateBinding HeaderText}"
                TextColor="Black" />

            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

```
public partial class MainViewTemplate : ContentPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(HeaderText), typeof(string), typeof(MainViewTemplate), default(string));

    public string HeaderText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(HeaderTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value);
    }

    public MainViewTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Using ControlTemplate x:key=""template

```
<control:MainViewTemplate
x:Class="demo3.template.Page1"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:control="clr-namespace:demo3.template"
ControlTemplate="{StaticResource template1}"
HeaderText="Main view">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Margin="10" BackgroundColor="Green">
        <Label Text="Test" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
  </control:MainViewTemplate>
```

The screenshot :

[image]

More detailed info about ControlTemplate, please take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template#substitute-content-into-a-contentpresenter

Comment: Trying this now. I remember trying with a content.resources as well, but didn't work. I will see again.

Comment: @DiddanDo Yes, don't remember to set ControlTemplate="{StaticResource template1}" in your code.

Comment: Yes i know. I just did now, but now i cannot see the content on top either.

Comment: No idea why it does not work. I am following your code line by line.

Comment: Not finding the right key? Right now, it is not showing content from the template or the page itself. With my code it was showing code from the template top part.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706933/xamarin-forms-controltemplate-doesnt-display-contentpresenter?rq=1 Maybe has a correlation to this.

Comment: If i add "var e = this.BindingContext;" just to see if it has a bindingcontext to initializecomponent(); in the mainviewtemplate, it says "null". is that supposed to happen?

Comment: @DiddanDo Can you try [ControlTemplate demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/templates-controltemplatedemos/), clicking ContentPresenterPage.

Comment: that worked, will use it to try to implement in my project